# On iOS 8, ​​the ALAssetsLibrary does not show all the "Saved Photos" but only the "Recently added"

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios8, alassetslibrary

In my apps I've always used the library [photopicker-ios](https://github.com/guicocoa/photopicker-ios) to show a picker of photos/videos. It has a few unique features not found Apple's implementation `UIImagePickerController`.

It makes use of the `ALAssetsLibrary` and, specifically, `ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos`, which until iOS 7 correctly showed all the "Saved Photos" (and videos) on the device. With iOS 8, however, the album "Saved Photos" was replaced by "Recently added", showing only photos and videos taken in the last 30 days.

In my knowledge, this new limitation is not documented. Do we have any confirmation? In the meantime, can we take some workaround?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25973151/657104.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is no longer present on iOS 8.0.2. Therefore, it was a bug in iOS 8.0.

**UPDATE:** This supposition is confirmed by the [changelog](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1758?):

> Fixes an issue that prevented some apps from accessing photos from the
>   Photo Library