# iOS & Swift - How can I get and save a UIImage from the user?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, xcode6, camera-roll

I am writing a Swift app for iOS. I want to know how to get an image from the user's camera roll (or whatever they're calling it these days) and save it locally within the app so that I can reference it later. How would one go about this? As an example, let's say I want to get the image and set it as the image for a UIImageView in my storyboard.

Comment: Look up ALAssetsLibrary

Comment: i think this link will help you a lot [check here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730830/how-to-get-only-images-in-the-camera-roll-using-photos-framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimagepickercontroller_class/index.html) combined with [`NSUserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) will do.

For you it will be a two part task. First you will have to capture the image with a `UIImagePickerController` and then either store it in their photo library, or store it on their device with `NSUserDefaults`.

To store an image with `NSUserDefaults`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648518/save-images-in-nsuserdefaults).

Comment: User Defaults for images? Really?

Comment: It's still a bad idea. You could just store the images in the local sandbox and refer to them with a more appropriate persistence mechanism.

Comment: You should persist images via the file manager, or core data.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my combination.

Saving Image:

```
let imageData = NSData(data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedimage))
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
var docs: String = paths[0] as! String
let fullPath = docs.stringByAppendingPathComponent("yourNameImg.png")
let result = imageData.writeToFile(fullPath, atomically: true)

print(fullPath)
```

Get Image:

```
let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask    = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask
if let paths            = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
{
    if paths.count > 0
    {
        if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String
        {
            let readPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("yourNameImg.png")
            let image    = UIImage(contentsOfFile: readPath)

            UploadImagePreview.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

We can try with Photos Framework to fetch the last saved image.

```
var fetchOptions: PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]

var fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions)

if (fetchResult.firstObject != nil) {
    var lastAsset: PHAsset = fetchResult.lastObject as! PHAsset

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(lastAsset, targetSize: self.UploadImagePreview.bounds.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler: { (result, info) -> Void in
        self.UploadImagePreview.image = result
    })
}
```

Comment: @ Rodrigo: It works only when a complete path  of the image is given.

Answer (score 2):

Ray Wenderlich has a [great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76285/beginning-core-image-swift) for using a `UIImagePickerController` to select an image and then using the `AssetsLibrary` to save to an album.

There is also info on using image filters that is more than you asked for in the tutorial.

Comment: The only way I know to not conform to the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate is to not also conform to UINavigationControllerDelegate.  The UIPicker needs a nav controller.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the UIImage object, you can save the image in a doc dir with the following code

```
let imageData = NSData(data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(wineImage.image))
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
var docs: String = paths[0] as! String
let fullPath = docs.stringByAppendingPathComponent("yourNameImg.png")
let result = imageData.writeToFile(fullPath, atomically: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a `UIImagePickerController` as Brian mentioned, once you have the selected image use this file manager approach. I don't recommend using `NSUserDefaults` to store images as it goes against [Apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html):

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage)
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let imagePath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("cached.png")

if !imageData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: false)
{
    println("not saved")
} else {
    println("saved")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imagePath, forKey: "imagePath")
}
```