# Fetch photos from camera roll which are clicked by the camera using PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am using PHPhotoLibrary to access camera roll photos. But it is getting all images, like downloaded images, screenshots, Facebook Image etc. I need images which are clicked by the camera.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this link may help you:

[How to get only images in the camera roll using Photos Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730830/how-to-get-only-images-in-the-camera-roll-using-photos-framework)

> Through some experimentation we discovered a hidden property not
>   listed in the documentation (assetSource). Basically you have to do a
>   regular fetch request, then use a predicate to filter the ones from
>   the camera roll. This value should be 3.
>
> Sample code:

```
//fetch all assets, then sub fetch only the range we need
var assets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions)

assets.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (obj, idx, bool) -> Void in
    results.addObject(obj)
}

var cameraRollAssets = results.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "assetSource == %@", argumentArray: [3]))
results = NSMutableArray(array: cameraRollAssets)
```