# How to hide iCloud images in picker while picking image from photos using Photos Framework

Tags: ios, icloud, photo, phasset, photosframework

In my app, I am allowing the user to select photos from the album, but here I want to hide iCloud images for selection. I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28063530/1635315) but not working for me, the iCloud image is visible to select. Picker should show local images and camera roll images for selection.

I tried below AssetCollection subtypes:

`PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumMyPhotoStream` : found iCloud image `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary`: found iCloud image

Any idea how to do that? Which `PHAssetCollectionSubtype` should have to use?

Comment: did you tried albumRegular?

Comment: Yes, I tried albumRegular, as I don't have albums in photos app so not found any images.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly with iCloud images?

1. There is the iCloud Photo-Library. The images are just normal assets in the All Photos album. There is no way to hide them as the iCloud Photo Library does not differantiate between what's on the device and what's in the Cloud. The only thing you can do is prevent network access (cloud download), when you request the full resolution image/data, video data for the asset.
2. There are "Shared Photostreams and "My Photostream". These are not part of "All Photos" and in separate albums. These you can just exclude by not including the albums in the interface